# Keras CNN TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I tried to set up a binary CNN with Keras using `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow()`. I have looked at other threads with similar issues, but still haven't been able to get the model to run. 
My images are stored in the correct tree structure, and I don't think that any of them are corrupted or br
I am using Keras 2.2.5 and TensorFlow 1.15.0.

When I try to train the model, I get the following error:

```py
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:1033: The name tf.assign_add is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign_add instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:1020: The name tf.assign is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3005: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.

Epoch 1/10
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:190: The name tf.get_default_session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_session instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:197: The name tf.ConfigProto is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:207: The name tf.global_variables is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.global_variables instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:216: The name tf.is_variable_initialized is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.is_variable_initialized instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:223: The name tf.variables_initializer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer instead.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-62d341ff3a92> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('time', '', '\nhistory = model.fit_generator(\n    train_generator, \n    steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) / BATCH_SIZE,\n    epochs=EPOCHS,\n    validation_data=val_generator,\n    validation_steps=len(X_val) / BATCH_SIZE\n)')

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2115             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2116             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2117                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2118             return result
   2119 

</usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-60> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189 
    190         if callable(arg):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1191         else:
   1192             st = clock2()
-> 1193             exec(code, glob, local_ns)
   1194             end = clock2()
   1195             out = None

<timed exec> in <module>()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1656             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1657             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1658             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1659 
   1660     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    213                 outs = model.train_on_batch(x, y,
    214                                             sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 215                                             class_weight=class_weight)
    216 
    217                 outs = to_list(outs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight)
   1447             ins = x + y + sample_weights
   1448         self._make_train_function()
-> 1449         outputs = self.train_function(ins)
   1450         return unpack_singleton(outputs)
   1451 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2977                     return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2978 
-> 2979             return self._call(inputs)
   2980         else:
   2981             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
   2915                 array_vals.append(
   2916                     np.asarray(value,
-> 2917                                dtype=tf.as_dtype(tensor.dtype).as_numpy_dtype))
   2918         if self.feed_dict:
   2919             for key in sorted(self.feed_dict.keys()):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Here is my Keras code:

```py
#Establish model parameters
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Reshape((-1,))) #replaced Flatten()
model.add(layers.Dense(64))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.add(layers.Activation('sigmoid'))

#Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()


#Image generator
data_aug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    featurewise_center=False, # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
    samplewise_center=False, # set each sample mean to 0
    featurewise_std_normalization=False, # divide inputs by std of the dataset
    samplewise_std_normalization=False, # divide each input by its std
    zca_whitening=False, # apply ZCA whitening
    rotation_range=15, # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
    zoom_range =0.15, # Randomly zoom image 
    width_shift_range=0.1, # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
    height_shift_range=0.1, # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
    horizontal_flip=True, # randomly flip images
    vertical_flip=False) # randomly flip images

#Prepare image generator for training dataset
train_generator = data_aug.flow(np.array(X_train), y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

#Prepare validation generator
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255)

val_generator = val_datagen.flow(np.array(X_val), y_val, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

#Fit model 1
%%time

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator, 
    steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) / BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=len(X_val) / BATCH_SIZE
)
```

Anyone see anything wrong with the Keras code? Or is it possible that there is an issue with the image pre-processing steps?

Comment: Has the author ceased existence?

Comment: Are any of your images missing or corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

This model looks fine except `.fit_generator()` is deprecated. You need to use `.fit()` instead. Also try using the latest [Python](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package_location) and tensorflow version which you can upgrade using the below code:

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

There could be a problem with your dataset or while passing the arguments for processing the images. You can use the [flow_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) api which will take the images and consider its label itself from the folder directory. However the `.flow()` apis is also running fine when I tried replicating the same error using `fashion_mnist` dataset. (Please check this [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/e4515aab3038897f17ba1ebb85c17630/58842687.ipynb) for your reference)